# Workflow Conditional if Date is in Decemeber

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to trigger a workflow on record change and if the scheduled date-time is in in the Month of December.  Is this possible without a custom workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't believe you can do this with out of the box CRM. Your best bet is to use something like [CRM DateTime Workflow Utilities](https://crmdatetimeworkflowutilities.codeplex.com/)

You can get the date as a UTC string and search for the month (something like "-12-") in that string.